# Display values after Thread in the activity

Tags: android

I am trying to display the setText values `magX, mahY, magZ and teslaXYZ` after the Thread but nothing is being display when I comment the `Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);` as well try catch block all value are being displayed in the actvity. Can someone explain me my mistake?

I have added the thread to delay the sensor event reading

I apreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

            try {

                Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);

                float magX = sensorEvent.values[0];
                float magY = sensorEvent.values[1];
                float magZ = sensorEvent.values[2];

                magneticX.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[0]));
                magneticY.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[1]));
                magneticZ.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[2]));

                double teslaXYZ = (Math.sqrt((magX * magX) + (magY * magY)
                        + (magZ * magZ)));
                magneticT.setText(Double.toString(teslaXYZ));

                try {
                    JSONObject tesla = new JSONObject();
                    tesla.put("tesla", teslaXYZ);
                    telsaString = tesla.toString();
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(telsaString);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

onSensorChanged is being called from the UI?!?! if so this a **BAD** idea calling *sleep* on the UI thread. If not, the u should *post* the event to the UI thread by calling

```
 magnetic.post(new Runnable(){

  public void run(){

 magneticX.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[0]));
                 magneticY.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[1]));
                magneticZ.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[2]));


 double teslaXYZ = (Math.sqrt((magX * magX) + (magY * magY)
                   + (magZ * magZ)));
                 magneticT.setText(Double.toString(teslaXYZ)); } }
```